# Is NSDocument subclass a model object or not?

Tags: swift, cocoa, model, nsdocument

I am writing a multi-document application for macOS Swift. I'm starting with the Document app template provided by Xcode. It's unclear whether it’s an object model or not. Is `NSDocument` the model or is the data contained therein the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple [says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/documents_data_and_pasteboard/developing_a_document-based_app) that a “document’s data is called the data model”:

> In the Cocoa document architecture, your document is represented by a custom subclass of `NSDocument`. The `NSDocument` class provides most of the behavior for managing your document. In your subclass, you override or fine-tune this behavior by providing custom code for reading and writing document data. A document’s data is called the *data model.* Each `NSDocument` has its own `NSWindowController`, which in turn creates an NSWindow object for displaying the document content.
>
> Because a document-based app handles multiple documents that are open at the same time, it uses `NSDocumentController` to manage them. Cocoa provides most of the infrastructure for managing your documents. With file coordination, version management, and conflict resolution among other documents, it provides the easiest path to using iCloud.
>
> [image]

This `NSDocument` subclass imports `Cocoa` and is deeply entangled with UI layer code, so one would be hard-pressed to call a true model object (though it is a useful abstraction). Many of us strive to keep true “model” objects free of UI/OS dependencies.

In short, the data managed by the `NSDocument` is more aptly considered the “model”.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort in helping me get my head around Apple's architecture. Microsoft is a strong advocate of MVVM suffixes and prefixes for annotation. After some thought, however, it pollutes the domain-specific terminology with its architectural role. It's akin to the old Microsoft Hungarian Notation where variable and object identifiers are prefixed with their assigned type, providing extraneous information already provided by their declaration statements. While I can infer the object model, the lack of the MVVM annotations made me question it.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple, no, `NSDocument` is not a model. See the following diagram from Apple's [Developing a Document-Based App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/documents_data_and_pasteboard/developing_a_document-based_app). Notice that both the `NSDocument` and the UI (`contentViewController`, an `NSViewController`) access the model.

[image]